# Clearing Notification Icons on Windows Mobile Created by another application

Tags: windows-mobile, notifications

There are plenty of examples of how to create a notification using Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.Notification.

What I need to do is dispose a notification created by another application.

My application starts another application and that application is putting up a notification that I want to dispose of programatically.

Is there a way to get a handle to another applications Notification Icon and dispose it.

Comment: +1 Good question. If you had the app, you could disable that notification. If you don't have that app, however, you may have to either uninstall the app or reset the device.